# How can ı see text after submit form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have a form and validation. I need form is full and after submitting just Successfull text. ı wrote that code but text is coming even if the form is not full

```
$(function() {
$('form').on("submit",function(e) { 
    $("#_supportFormContainer").removeClass("col");
    $("#_supportFormContainer").css("display", "none");
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#contact-text-div').show();// or fade, css display however you'd like.
    }, 3000);
});});
```

Comment: please add the complete form to your question with all the elements that are used in the JS so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: have you tried adding a listener to the jQuery submit event https://api.jquery.com/submit/?

Comment: @MarkBaijens ı added

Comment: @asdru I tried.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide a form when it is submitted I would append a listener to the submit event of the *form*

```
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
      $(this).hide()
  });
```

Then, in order to show the div, I would also add `$("#myElem").show();`.

If you also want to block the page reload you can add `event.preventDefault()`, in order to avoid the use of `onsubmit="return false;"` on the form itself.

But maybe you also want to hide `$("#myElem")` on document ready, so you can add `$("#myElem").hide()`

Putting all together, the script become

```
$(function() {
  $("#myElem").hide()
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).hide();
      $("#myElem").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: ı can see text when ı did not filling form  when ı click button